# Syntax error at position 7: no viable alternative at input 'table' with Cassandra version 2.0.3

Tags: cassandra

Environment: Cassandra and CLI version is 2.0.3 OS Windows7 Enterprise, 64 Bit.

ran cassendra-cli.bat, When running the create table command I get following:

[default@unknown] create table us(name varchar); Syntax error at position 7: no viable alternative at input 'table'

Any idea why its throwing error ?

Answer (score 4):

You're using CQL instead of CLI format. Try again using `cqlsh.bat` rather than `cassandra-cli.bat`.

Comment: I am on Windows, When I do py cqlsh I get following:
Unable to create process using '/bin/sh cqlsh'

Comment: If I do 'python cqlsh' I get following, File 'cqlsh', line 95 except ImportantError, e:  SyntaxErroe: Invalid syntax

Comment: Worked after downgrading python to 2.7.x

Comment: @user204069 Thanks! I was facing the same error with a Python 3.x version.